# Composition Functions (Advanced Functions)

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Question: a) Given the functions $f(x) = x + 2$ and $g(x) = 3^x$, determine an equation for (f ∘ g)(x) and (g ∘ f)(x).

b) Determine all values for $x$ for which $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$.

*For part a), I got the equation:

$(f ∘ g)(x) = 3^x + 2$

and

$(g ∘ f)(x) = 3^{x+2}$

But I don't know if it's right or not. I'd appreciate if anyone can tell me if I got it right or not. And if not, what I did wrong. I believe it's right because I used the simplified formula of $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$. But still, I just want to make sure that I'm correct.

For part c.) I don't know how to solve the question at all. Here's what I started with:

$3^x + 2 = 3^{x+2}$

But I don't know how to continue on. I don't know how to get rid of the 2. I'm trying to figure out a way where I can get all the bases to be the same so I can solve for x. But I don't think it's going to work like that and I don't know what else to do. I'd be thankful if anyone can help me out!

Comment: Part a) looks good, for part b); Hint: $3^{x+2}=3^{2}3^{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for the  first pat is correct. For solving $3^{x}+2=3^{x+2}$ write this as $3^{x} (3^{2}-1)=2$ or $3^{x}=\frac  1 4$. Take  logarithm  to finish.

Comment: I understand how to solve it now but the one question that I have is: how did you get $3^x(3^2 - 1) = 2$? I understand, that you sent $3^x$ to the other side to isolate $2$, but how were you able to factor and receive the $3^x(3^2 -1)$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @Panda48490 $a^{x+y}=a^{x}a^{y}$ for all positive numbers $a$ and real numbers $x,y$. So $3^{x+2}=3^{x} 3^{2}$.